# How to check that current user has edit permission to a webpart in Sharepoint 2007 and 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I have a webpart. If current user has edit permission then I have to display some information in webpart content.

How to check that current user has edit permission to a webpart in Sharepoint 2007 and 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the SPWebPartManager.GetPermissions method, this should let you know if a user has access to edit a web part.  More info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.spwebpartmanager.getpermissions.aspx).

Here is a [link](http://64.4.11.251/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.permissions.aspx) with the enumerations of Permissions.  There is also a link on this page to demonstrate how this is used in SharePoint 2007

Comment: Your welcome. It looks like it is the same for 2007 and 2010.  It seems like 2007 had two ways but they depricated the other one in favor of this method.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Matt here is my code..

```
public Boolean HasEditPermission
        {
            get
            {   
                SPWebPartManager sPWebPartManager = (SPWebPartManager) SPWebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(Page);
                Permissions permissions = sPWebPartManager.GetPermissions(this);
                if (permissions == Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.Permissions.AllProperties)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }
```